# Sending Bots Name Not Users Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So here is my code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [4611] });

let targetChannel = '906686653874176090' //target channel

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready! - Made By Woodington');
});  

client.on('messageCreate', gotMessage);

function gotMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.channel.id !== targetChannel) { 
        client.channels.fetch(targetChannel)  
        .then(channel => channel.send(msg.content + `${client.user.tag}`)) 
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

What it does is forward messages to another channel, with the users Discord tag at the bottom. However, it sends the bots Discord name and not the original senders. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `client` variable which is your own bot. You need to make use of the `msg` parameter you received within the event. That's the reason why your bot sends its own tag, because `client.user.tag` equals `YourBot#0000`.

To send the author's tag, replace `client.user.tag` with the following:

```
msg.author.tag
```

This will return `Author's Username#0000`